# Problema con condicional en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy desarrollando un código en python para presentar la tabla del campeonato brasileño y el primer y segundo lugar. Sin embargo, no estoy haciendo la condicional de la forma correcta para el segundo colocado. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
m = []

#Entrada do número de times do campeonato brasileiro
n = (int(input("Digite o número de times referente ao campeonato brasileiro: ")))


#Preenchendo a matriz do campeonameto brasileiro

for i in range(n):
    linha = []
    linha.append(input ("Digite o nome do time:  " + str(i) + ':'))
    gp = (int(input("Digite o número de gols positivos: ")))
    gn = (int(input("Digite o número de gols tomados: ")))
    vf = (int(input("Digite o número de vitórias fora de casa: ")))
    vc = (int(input("Digite o número de vitórias em casa: ")))
    E = (int(input("Digite o número de empates: ")))
    P = 5 * gp - gn + 3 * vf + 2 * vc + E
    linha.append(P)
    m.append(linha)
    verificador = m[0] [1]
    pos1 = 0
    pos2 = 0


# Verificando o primeiro e segundo colocado do campeonato

for i in range(n):
    if (m[i] [1]> verificador):
        verificador = m [i] [1]
        pos1 = i
    elif(m[i] [1] < verificador):
        verificador = m[i] [1]
        pos2 = i



#Imprimindo a matriz do campeoneto brasileiro
for i in range(n):
    print(m[i])


print ('\nO primeiro colocado no campeonato brasileiro: ', m[pos1] [0], '\n')
print ('O segundo colocado no campeonato brasileiro: ', m[pos2] [0])
```

Comment: Hola Ana, bienvenida a [es.so], me surge una duda ¿Qué pasa si hay un empate a puntos en las posiciones?¿Es decir, si hay dos equipos igualados a puntos en la primera posición cual retornas? Si al final vas a necesitar conocer más posiciones te podrías plantear ordenar simplemente la lista según el segundo elemento de sus sublistas, bien con `list.sort` o `sorted` de Python estándar o creando el algoritmo propio por ejemplo un bubble sort es simple de implementar.